# Cloudwatch Subscription Filter does not ingest logs in Kinesis Data Stream

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have developed a web application using API Gateway and Lambda functions. To capture and process logs from this application, I set up a subscription filter for a Kinesis Data Stream. Despite having logs in CloudWatch each time the application is used, I am unable to see these logs in my Kinesis Data Stream.

I have attempted to use both ShardIteratorTypes, "Latest" and "TRIM_HORIZON," but have not seen any results in my Kinesis Data Stream.